# Is possible to use Ros with pic32 microcontroller?

Tags: rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI
I have a pic32 ethernet kit microcontroller, and i want connect it with another pic32 and  with the master in a pc using ROS and the protocol TCP/IP. Is it possible?
I read that there are the rosserial package and the rosc library, but i don't understand how they work, so if is possible  what 's the better solution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143416/is-possible-to-use-ros-with-pic32-microcontroller?/) by [mrpiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4072/mrpiccolo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-03-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billtecteacher](https://answers.ros.org/users/9406/billtecteacher/) on 2014-03-23**:
I have used the rosserial with ardunino and it works great.  The code is written in C.  You can use tcp/ip with PIC perhaps ROS bridge.

**Comment by [mrpiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4072/mrpiccolo/) on 2014-03-24**:
Are you sure that with rosserial i can send using json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rosserial is sending receiving and sending ros topics or messages.  The message will need a ros header on it but could be a string of some length that contains your json information you are trying to convey.  Ros serial is like ros bridge but connects to a serial line.  Ros bridge uses tcp/ip but once again it is I think a ros topic message and above applys to it.

---

Originally posted by [billtecteacher](https://answers.ros.org/users/9406/billtecteacher/) with karma: 101 on 2014-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mrpiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4072/mrpiccolo/) on 2014-03-26**:
Thanks for the answer, but if i want use the ethernet port instead of a serial port?